# how to List<T>.Find(Predicate<T>) Method in messageBox.Show

Tags: c#, wpf, list

error

[image]

list class

[image]

create list

[image]

I did the installer, but here is such an error, I am suffering for the second day and I have no idea how I can convert it to a string for output, since the usual methods do not work. Might be a stupid mistake, but I hope for a quick answer

I tried to convert in the usual ways (string) or ToString() but for some reason it doesn’t work, maybe I didn’t write it correctly, I googled nothing about this

all code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace visualnstaller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public class Part
    {
        public string PartName { get; set; }

        public string PartReq { get; set; }
    }


    public class GetRequest
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;
        string _addres;
        public string Response { get; set; }

        public GetRequest(string address)
        {
            _addres = address;

        }

        public void Run()
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_addres);
            request.Method = "Get";

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (stream != null) Response = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public class Download
    {
        public Download(string name, string req)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var completed = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
                    progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                };
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(req), name);
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    completed.Set();
                };
                completed.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    
        public List<Part> numbers = new List<Part>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            /*     request     */
            var request = new GetRequest("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MrKuBu/a24ddd8a331b0b54f6cc25b577d2fd9d/raw/154a1f194967d1a248b4627b9565586dc8bc2d1b/Example%2520file%2520downloader");
            request.Run();
            var response = request.Response;
            var json = JObject.Parse(response);

        
            foreach (var item in json)
            {
            

                CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox { IsChecked = false };
                ItemsControl ic = new ItemsControl();
                ic.Items.Add(item.Key);

                Programm.Items.Add(ic);


                changeCheckBox(checkBox2, (string)item.Value, item.Key);

            
            }
        }

    

        void changeCheckBox(CheckBox item, string itemValue, string itemName)
        {
            item.Checked += Item_Checked;
            item.Unchecked += Item_Uncheked;

            ProgrammCheckBox.Items.Add(item);



            void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                numbers.Add(new Part {PartName = itemName, PartReq = itemValue });
                MessageBox.Show(numbers.Find(x => x.PartName.Contains(itemName)));
            
            }

            void Item_Uncheked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                numbers.Remove(new Part() {PartName = itemName, PartReq = itemValue });
            }


        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the actual code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically all your code, error messages etc. should be as copy-pasted text, not images/links.

Comment: What string do you want to output through MessageBox? `numbers.Find(...)` is returning a `Part` object which has two properties inside. If you want to output the `PartName` you should add: `numbers.Find(x => x.PartName.Contains(itemName)).PartName`. Whereas if you want to show `PartReq` you should change it to: `numbers.Find(x => x.PartName.Contains(itemName)).PartReq`. If you want both properties to be shown you could do: `Part foundPart = numbers.Find(x => x.PartName.Contains(itemName)); MessageBox.Show($"{foundPart.PartName}, {foundPart.PartReq}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find returns a single item of the generic type. I don't know how you expect to display the item, when MessageBox.Show takes a string as the first argument. Maybe you want to format the object to display the properties?

```cs
var part = numbers.Find(x => x.PartName.Contains(itemName));
MessageBox.Show($"Name: {part.PartName}, Req: {part.PartReq}");
```

Comment: You could also consider overriding the method `ToString()` of the class `Part`.
`public override string ToString() => $"Name: {PartName}, Req: {PartReq}"`. Then you would do: `MessageBox.Show(numbers.Find(x => x.PartName.Contains(itemName)).ToString());`